# Automatically add new row with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a bunch of data in the `tables` variable and I want to make a lot of grid view, but I can't make the new row for each 2 grid.

Here's my code:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-40" ng-repeat="table in tables" style="background:{{table.warna}}">{{table.fstRoomName}}<br/>{{table.fsiStatus}}</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some clarification, here is another answer. Use CSS to apply some margin after every 2 items.

```
<div class="padded col col-40" ng-repeat="table in tables" style="background:{{table.warna}}">{{table.fstRoomName}}<br/>{{table.fsiStatus}}</div>
```

CSS:

```
.padded:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you said you wanted some empty space after every two items, and there it is! If you want more columns that is another question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Yeah, I need 2 column and after that I add a row, I want do it with ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your rows inside another div, and use the `$odd` variable from the `ng-repeat` to conditionally add another row.

```
<div ng-repeat="table in tables">
    <div class="col col-40" style="background:{{table.warna}}">{table.fstRoomName}}<br/>{{table.fsiStatus}}</div>
    <div ng-if="$odd">
        This will be visible every second item.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just got a one single column.

Comment: this is the code, right ?
`<div ng-if="$odd">
          <div class="row"></div>
      </div>`

Comment: My code is in the answer. Please specify what your objective is (maybe with a picture) so i can help you further.

Comment: Ah ok, so you just want some empty space every two items?

Comment: Yeah. I need a new row.

Comment: I don't understand. when i'm not using the `<div ng-if="$odd">This will be visible every second item.</div>` the grid system is work. But when I'm use it, the grid system stop working and make only one single column. Can you explain to me please ?

Comment: I created a plnkr to demonstrate my example: https://plnkr.co/edit/0sMjHP80Hijoacmr8544?p=preview.

Comment: Yes, only one column with an extra row every two items.

Comment: Yeah,  are you have another option to create 2 columns ??

Comment: Are you using Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: Nope. Only using ionic css, but if i have to use it, its not a problem

Comment: You should be able to use Ionic row and col. Try searching the documentation.

Comment: I have use it. The `.col` and the `.col-40`. That's the col. The row, I need generate it every 2 col

Comment: Can you post an illustration of your desired result? I do not follow you 100%.

Comment: I just need something like this  https://imgur.com/YmyJ7O6 (sorry, I just draw it on my phone). It just 2 column with many row.

Comment: Read here http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/using-the-grid/. And set a div with class="row" outside your repeat. And your "repeat"-div should have class="col col-50"

Comment: I have tried it, and here's the result. Please take a look @henrikmerlander

http://imgur.com/y6y3rER